# Subsetting using two data frames

Tags: r

I have a large unscaled dataset (data1) with a random patient identifier MaskID. I am trying to pull out all observations by MaskID that are also found in a smaller test set (data2)

In theory this is what I am trying to do but I know this is not correct:

```
data3 <- data1[data1$MaskID == data2$MaskID]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Very close:

```
data3 <- data1[data1$MaskID %in% data2$MaskID,]
```

Comment: Close perhaps in character count, but had two errors that prevented success: use of == and failure to put the comma in "[" to allow selection by row.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

# 1. Data set with random patient identifier 'mask_id'

# 1.1. First data set
df_one <- data.frame(
  dataset_id = 1,
  mask_id = unique(as.integer(runif(10, min = 0, max = 15))))

# 1.2. Second data set
df_two <- data.frame(
  dataset_id = 2,
  mask_id = unique(as.integer(runif(10, min = 0, max = 15))))

# 2. Common rows with the same 'mask_id'
common_features <- intersect(df_one$mask_id, df_two$mask_id)

# 3. Select rows from first data set
df_one %>% filter(mask_id %in% common_features)

# 4. More brief form
df_one[df_one$mask_id %in% df_two$mask_id, ]
```